# Wrong multi-dimensional array variables increase in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, comma-operator

I have the curiosity to know the behaviour, in C, of a multidimensional array increased as below:

```
int x[10][10];

y = x[++i, ++j];
```

I know that is the wrong way. I just want to know what the compiler do in this case and what will be the consequence if a programmer do this in his code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the comma operator, misused. `++i, ++j` yields the value of `j + 1` and has 2 side effects (modifying `i` and `j`). The whole thing basically means `++i; y = x[++j]`. Which will work or not, depending on the type of `y`.

> what will be the consequence if a programmer do this in his code

Well, most likely other programmers will give him/her murderous looks.

Comment: ahahah. Nice answer to the second question. +1!! ;)

Comment: I just don't understand a thing: the ++i disappeared in this case??

Comment: @Kyrol It didn't disappear. It's still performed (you can check `i` afterwards) but its value is thrown away. In C every expression has side effects and yields a value. It just so happens that in this case the value yielded does not depend on `i`. But the side effects are there.